# How to query floatfield in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a FloatField which can have values like 22.33405, 33.567 etc. Now, I need to query using only upto 2 places after decimal like below

```
#find all objects with value equal to 22.33
ModelName.objects.filter(field = 22.33)
```

Is it possible to do so - can I round off or just take first 2 places after decimal?

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
ModelName.objects.filter(field__gte=22.33, field__lt=(22.33 + 0.01))
```

or

```
ModelName.objects.filter(field__range=(22.33, 22.33 + 0.01))
```

[range lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#range)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. If you need this level of accuracy then you should be using `DecimalField`.